# How to test HiddenField Server Control's ValueChanged method

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

My understanding is that viewstate controls that hiddenfields or any other read only control have not been interfered with between postback on the client side.

But How do I come about checking this is actually working.
How can i simulate a postback with changed value in a hidden field to see what actually happen.
I have implemented a sub:

```
Protected Sub HF1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       Handles HF1.ValueChanged
```

How can i test this? I tried inspect element in firefox but I cannot even find the hidden fields. I can see then on the page source but I cannot edit this.

Comment: It sounds like you have some fundamentals to learn before any useful answers can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you're aware that changing the HiddenField will not post back automatically. Instead, it calls [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.valuechanged.aspx) method when one of the server control post back.

Here is how you test - you can change the hidden field value at client side. Then click PostBack button to post back to server. HF1_ValueChanged will fire if hidden field is changed.

### ASPX

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HF1" Value="1" 
   OnValueChanged="HF1_ValueChanged" />
<div id="button">Click this text to change Hidden Field</div><br/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    Text="PostBack"/><br/>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $("#<%= HF1.ClientID %>").val("2");
            alert("HF has new value: " + $("#<%= HF1.ClientID %>").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void HF1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This method should be called 
    // only if hidden field is changed at client side.
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```